# Game Messing Up in Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

In Xcode 5 my game worked fine, when my computer updated to Xcode 6 it became buggy. I do not know exactly what happened.  I think it might have to do something with the NSStrings connected to the text that shows the score. Whenever the score goes to 1, the game resets. Maybe its something coded wrong in `touchesBegan:withEvent:`?

The game is a submarine that goes through a cave and earns points for every half second alive and earns coins when the sub hits the coins. Below is the code parts that it might be, but I don't know where the error is even coming from.

```
-(void)NewGame{
    Coin.hidden = YES;
    Coin2.hidden = YES;

    Ruby.hidden = YES;
    Ruby2.hidden = YES;

    Intro1.hidden = NO;
    Intro2.hidden = NO;
    Intro3.hidden = NO;
    Intro8.hidden = NO;
    IntroC.hidden = NO;

    Start = YES;
    ScoreNumber = 0;
    Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: 0"];
    CoinNumber = 0;
    CoinCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Coins: 0"];


    Intro3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HighScore: %i", HighScoreAttack];

    IntroC.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Total Coins: %i", TotalCoins];
}

-(void)Fishmove {
    [self Collision];

    Submarine.center = CGPointMake(Submaine.center.x, Submarine.center.y + y);


    Obstacle.center = CGPointMake(Obstacle.center.x - 10, Obstacle.center.y);
    Obstacle2.center = CGPointMake(Obstacle2.center.x - 10, Obstacle2.center.y);
    Bottom1.center = CGPointMake(Bottom1.center.x - 10, Bottom1.center.y);
    Bottom2.center = CGPointMake(Bottom2.center.x - 10, Bottom2.center.y);
    Bottom3.center = CGPointMake(Bottom3.center.x - 10, Bottom3.center.y);
    Bottom4.center = CGPointMake(Bottom4.center.x - 10, Bottom4.center.y);
    Bottom5.center = CGPointMake(Bottom5.center.x - 10, Bottom5.center.y);
    Bottom6.center = CGPointMake(Bottom6.center.x - 10, Bottom6.center.y);
    Bottom7.center = CGPointMake(Bottom7.center.x - 10, Bottom7.center.y);
    Top1.center = CGPointMake(Top1.center.x - 10, Top1.center.y);
    Top2.center = CGPointMake(Top2.center.x - 10, Top2.center.y);
    Top3.center = CGPointMake(Top3.center.x - 10, Top3.center.y);
    Top4.center = CGPointMake(Top4.center.x - 10, Top4.center.y);
    Top5.center = CGPointMake(Top5.center.x - 10, Top5.center.y);
    Top6.center = CGPointMake(Top6.center.x - 10, Top6.center.y);
    Top7.center = CGPointMake(Top7.center.x - 10, Top7.center.y);
    Coin.center = CGPointMake(Coin.center.x - 10, Coin.center.y);
    Coin2.center = CGPointMake(Coin2.center.x - 10, Coin2.center.y);
    Ruby.center = CGPointMake(Ruby.center.x - 10, Ruby.center.y);
    Ruby2.center = CGPointMake(Ruby2.center.x - 10, Ruby2.center.y);


    if (Obstacle.center.x < 0) {
        Obstacle.hidden = NO;
        RadnomPosition = arc4random() %75;
        RadnomPosition = RadnomPosition +110;
        Obstacle.center = CGPointMake(560, RadnomPosition);
    }

    if (Obstacle2.center.x < 0) {
        Obstacle2.hidden = NO;
        RadnomPosition = arc4random() %75;
        RadnomPosition = RadnomPosition + 110;
        Obstacle2.center = CGPointMake(560, RadnomPosition);

    }


    if (Coin.center.x < 0) {
        Coin.hidden = NO;
        RadnomPosition = arc4random() %250;
        RadnomPosition = RadnomPosition +110;
        Coin.center = CGPointMake(560, RadnomPosition);
    }

    if (Coin2.center.x < 0) {
        Coin2.hidden = NO;
        RadnomPosition = arc4random() %150;
        RadnomPosition = RadnomPosition + 110;
        Coin2.center = CGPointMake(560, RadnomPosition);
    }
    if (Coin.center.y > 250) {
        Coin.hidden = YES;
    }
    if (Coin2.center.y > 250) {
        Coin2.hidden = YES;
    }
}


-(void)Scoring{
    ScoreNumber = ScoreNumber + 1;
    Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %i",ScoreNumber];
}

(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    if (Start == YES) {

        Intro1.hidden = YES;


        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target: self selector:@selector(Fishmove) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

        Scorer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(Scoring) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


        CoinScorer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(Collision) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        Start = NO;

        Obstacle2.hidden = NO;

        Coin.hidden = NO;
        Coin2.hidden = NO;

        RadnomPosition = arc4random() %75;
        RadnomPosition = RadnomPosition + 110;
        Obstacle.center = CGPointMake(570, RadnomPosition);

        RadnomPosition = arc4random() %75;
        RadnomPosition = RadnomPosition + 110;
        Obstacle2.center = CGPointMake(855, RadnomPosition);


        RadnomPosition = arc4random() %75;
        RadnomPosition = RadnomPosition + 110;
        Coin.center = CGPointMake(712.5, RadnomPosition);

        RadnomPosition = arc4random() %75;
        RadnomPosition = RadnomPosition + 110;
        Coin2.center = CGPointMake(997.5, RadnomPosition);


        RadnomPosition = arc4random() %75;
        RadnomPosition = RadnomPosition + 110;
        Ruby.center = CGPointMake(712.5, RadnomPosition);

        RadnomPosition = arc4random() %75;
        RadnomPosition = RadnomPosition + 110;
        Ruby2.center = CGPointMake(997.5, RadnomPosition);

        RadnomPosition = arc4random() %55;
        Top1.center = CGPointMake(560, RadnomPosition);
        RadnomPosition = RadnomPosition + 265;
        Bottom1.center = CGPointMake(560, RadnomPosition);

        RadnomPosition = arc4random() %55;
        Top2.center = CGPointMake(640, RadnomPosition);
        RadnomPosition = RadnomPosition + 265;
        Bottom2.center = CGPointMake(640, RadnomPosition);

        RadnomPosition = arc4random() %55;
        Top3.center = CGPointMake(720, RadnomPosition);
        RadnomPosition = RadnomPosition + 265;
        Bottom3.center = CGPointMake(720, RadnomPosition);

        RadnomPosition = arc4random() %55;
        Top4.center = CGPointMake(800, RadnomPosition);
        RadnomPosition = RadnomPosition + 265;
        Bottom4.center = CGPointMake(800, RadnomPosition);

        RadnomPosition = arc4random() %55;
        Top5.center = CGPointMake(880, RadnomPosition);
        RadnomPosition = RadnomPosition + 265;
        Bottom5.center = CGPointMake(880, RadnomPosition);

        RadnomPosition = arc4random() %55;
        Top6.center = CGPointMake(960, RadnomPosition);
        RadnomPosition = RadnomPosition + 265;
        Bottom6.center = CGPointMake(960, RadnomPosition);

        RadnomPosition = arc4random() %55;
        Top7.center = CGPointMake(1140, RadnomPosition);
        RadnomPosition = RadnomPosition + 265;
        Bottom7.center = CGPointMake(1140, RadnomPosition);
    }
    y = -7;
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    y = 7;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem will be in calling the method that resets the game at a time when it shouldn't be. You left out your Collision method so I don't know what that method does. I don't see how anything in the posted code that would reset the game.

I think the problem may lie in your Collision method because you have that called on a timer that is the same as your Scoring method. They are both called when the score goes to 1, and the Scoring method doesn't have anything in it that would reset the game.